# Creating label with id via Google Gmail API

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to create a label with a custom id using the node library for the Gmail API. The API has a request parameter for setting your own id however when I try to create the label I get the error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Invalid request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid request"
 }
}
```

The label is created with no problems when I don't give an id. However for my purposes I need to have a set standard label id. Anyone know what is going on here or if it is just a bug/error with the api?
You can try creating your own label for your account and see more of what I am talking about here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.labels.create

Code to create label:

```
var service = Google.gmail({version : 'v1', auth : oauth2Client});
service.users.labels.create({
    userId : 'user address here',
    labelListVisibility   : 'labelShow',
    messageListVisibility : 'show',
    name : 'label name here',
    id   : 'label id here'
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
       callback();
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say "The API has a request parameter for setting your own id", but the documentation at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/create does not show any such field as part of the `users.labels.create` endpoint.

If you look at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels, you'll see an immutable id field, but this is not writable, so the value for this is set by the system rather than by you.

The documentation for `users.labels.create` also indicates that a fully populated Users object will be returned, so you'll be able to know what the ID for the label you just created was. To do this with the node.js library, you set the callback function to have a second parameter, which will contain the results of the call. So it might look something like this:

```
var service = Google.gmail({version : 'v1', auth : oauth2Client});
service.users.labels.create({
    userId : 'user address here',
    labelListVisibility   : 'labelShow',
    messageListVisibility : 'show',
    name : 'label name here'
}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
       console.log( result );
       callback( result );
    }
});
```

As noted in the comments, you can also use `users.labels.list` to get a full list of labels for this user.

Comment: if you go to this link: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.labels.create 
and click on the request body it says "Add a property" and the id field is listed there. If you can't write to it why have the option? I was thinking it was immutable once it was initiated otherwise without knowing the id of the label it makes them almost useless.

Comment: you need to use labels.list() to determine label id <--> name mappings (though system labels have a consistent id). API Explorer cannot determine which fields are read-only and which are read-write. You need to check the docs for that information.

Comment: From what I can find on the docs you can only apply a label to a message by giving the label id. I read on another forum that you can use the label name as well but I can't find any supported docs for that.

Comment: Labels can only be applied to messages by *id* not by name.  If you find anywhere in the docs that suggest otherwise please let us know!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @prisoner and [gmail's api tester](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/create?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22labelListVisibility%22%3A%22labelShow%22%2C%22messageListVisibility%22%3A%22show%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22good%22%7D%7D), I was able to get my Python version working.

I started with the "quickstart.py" sample and muddled through all the oauth obstacles to get that code running. Getting quickstart.py working required finding [Rachel Hadad's comment](https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/issues/134) to get my credentials functioning properly. Google's documentation treats credentials as a minor issue but for me, it was key to getting their sample operating.

Once Google's sample code was running, I modified it as shown below to create a new label in my gmail account named `"foob"`. It took far too much reading and screwing around to figure out what the correct syntax to use was. Perhaps this "semiquickstart.py" will help someone who, like me, finds Google's documentation close to opaque.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import os.path
import sys
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import json
import requests
    
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels']
    
    
def main():
    """
    Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Creates a new Gmail label.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json',
                SCOPES,
            )
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    
    results = service.users().labels().create(
        userId='me',
        body={
            'labelListVisibility': 'labelShow',
            'messageListVisibility': 'show',
            'name': 'foob'
        }
    ).execute()
    print(results)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```