# setLabelIds method in google api not working

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to set label for the message while creating a new message in google api using the below code

```
private static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email, List<String> labelIds) throws MessagingException, IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    email.writeTo(bytes);
    String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes.toByteArray());
    Message message = new Message();
    **message.setLabelIds(labelIds);**
    message.setRaw(encodedEmail);

    return message;
}
```

But the label is not applied when the message is created for the first time. If I modify the message again then the label is set. Message modified using the below code

```
public static Message modifyMessage(Gmail service, String userId, String messageId, List<String> labelsToAdd, List<String> labelsToRemove) throws IOException {

    ModifyMessageRequest mods = new ModifyMessageRequest();

    if(labelsToAdd != null) {

        **mods.setAddLabelIds(labelsToAdd);**
    }

    if(labelsToRemove != null) {

        mods.setRemoveLabelIds(labelsToRemove);
    }

    Message message = service.users().messages().modify(userId, messageId, mods).execute();

    return message;
}
```

Comment: You can try implementing what [prisoner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446920/creating-label-with-id-via-google-gmail-api) have done in this previous SO question. Also there is an open [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3975) "that only allow an application to add/remove labels on messages in the user inbox." Try following this for updates about the said feature request. Hope this helps

Comment: @Mr.Robot thanks for the comment. I have code for creating label and your link to feature request doesn't match my issue. 
Making clear on the issue, when i set the labelIds while creating the message those label is not applied to the message created. It is only in the inbox and no other labels applied.